# Problems with WordPress menu links

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website with the `onepress-child` theme installed to add custom sections. It's an one page website.

Unfortunately, there are problems in the menu.
When you click on 'team', for example, nothing happens, the team section is not shown.

We have implemented this with `<section id ="xxx">`, so the respective sub-point should actually change the URL to "`https: //www.myDomain.tld/#xxx`", this does not happen!

I noticed that only in the registered mode the Menu points serve their purpose.

I have tried several times to find a solution, unfortunately without success.

If necessary, the website address can be provided.

Please help...

Comment: It looks like the problem is with Onepress-Child, because with Onepress, navigation with #xxx works fine.
Is anyone familiar with it?

Comment: formatted to make it easier to read. Please consider adding some code, and samples of what you have tried so far, with punctual questions. Read [ask] and how to make a [mcve] for more info.